# Install4j uninstall other program

Tags: install4j

The examples I have found of Install4j are simple wizard generated and don't show more complex logic.  I need some help to do the following in Install4j v6.

**Desired flow**

- Display the initial welcome screen
- check for other program being installed in Windows
- if other program is installed

  - Display message to user with confirmation to remove the other program
  - If confirmed, run the Windows Uninstaller for the other program
  - If not confirmed, exit the installer

I found question [27497335](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497335/can-install4j-detect-other-install4j-installations) which describes how to search the Windows Registry. Also question [10282814](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282814/how-to-silently-uninstall-mysql-on-32-and-64-bit-windows) which describes how to run a Windows uninstall.

I'm unsure of how to use these in my install to achieve the above flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To organize screen flow, use screen groups and set the condition expression on the screen groups or on single screens.

To see an example, add a "standalone updater" application on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step. It uses screen groups with condition expressions to behave in different ways depending on whether the installation is up to date or not.

Comment: Ingo ... Thanks for the quick reply on the weekend!  Are there any examples that I can use as a start for your suggested flow?